# How do I remove a stuck Nvidia-settings-experimental-310 package?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, package-management

When I boot up my Linux Box, I get the following message every time:

Sorry a problem occurred while installing software package: nvidia-settings-experimental-310.

I have older video card nvidia 7300 LE that only supports the 304 drivers and would like to resolve this error.

the software package: nvidia-settings-experimental-310 doesn't seem to be installed but its attempting to and I would like to remove this package.

How can I remove this package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like by cleaning ("apt-get clean")the deb packages under var/cache/apt/archives has certainly fixed the problem. I have restarted my box and no more error upon signing into Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do that in synaptic package manager . Fillup the search field with nvidia-settings-experimental-310 and that will be listed and you can remove that very easily from there .

Comment: Thanks!! I found it with your advice by using the Synaptic Package Manager, however since its not installed how do I remove it?   The only option I have available is "Mark for Installation"

Comment: well Then you have to uncheck the PPA of it , so then next time onwards it wont appear to be .

Comment: I'm not seeing a PPA for it

Comment: I think I found a way, I found the deb package under var/cache/apt/archives.  I ran apt-get clean on the archives directory to clean out the all the cached packages.  Hopefully once I restart I should not get this error anymore